# Create DFA with String of {a,b}

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I Want to Create Regular Expression from string of {a,b} that it contains neither the substring ab NOR ba?How I can do it?

Comment: What now, regular expression or DFA?

Answer (score 0):

If a string over $\{a,b\}$ contains neither $ab$ nor $ba$ as a substring, then all of its letters must be the same (why?). You can use this to create a regular expression for the language of all such strings.